# How can I setup free email forwarding using FreeNom and ImproveMX?

Tags: email, mx-record

I have a paid domain at FreeNom. It refers to a website hosted by GitHub. I want emails send to this domain to be forwarded to my personal email account. [ImproveMX](https://improvmx.com/) claims to facilitate this.

FreeNom suggests how to setup email forwarding [here](https://my.freenom.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=44). However, their suggestion differs from what ImproveMX suggests, seen in the image below. In either case, I get the error on ImproveMX stating "*MX records are not configured correctly*". Any ideas?

This is the view of my DNS management at FreeNom:
[image]

This is the view of ImproveMX:
[image]

Comment: You did not include the domain name. It is probably not possible to get a definitive answer without it.

Comment: Much easier to do this with Google domains, you should contact support

Comment: @Michael Hampton Does is really matter? I can't imagine that influencing the right steps to take.

Comment: @Jacob Evans, the Google MX forwarding is part of "G Suite", right? Which is not free, I think.

Comment: Domains.google.com registrar and nameservers with email forwarding, dnssec, dyndns, Private registration

Comment: @JacobEvans Okay, thanks. They don't support .eu domains unfortunately. Also, I'd like to get it to work with FreeNom - it should be possible.

Comment: Contact freenom support, it's not a requirement to support email forwarding and many of them invalidate DMARC

Comment: probably a much better idea, at least today, to use https://forwardemail.net/en/faq?domain=cregox.tk#how-is-it-free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ignore what FreeNom says and enter the following:
[image]

Note that there is no need for the '@' in the name field.